# Вывод дней недели

Tags: php, дата

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Над каждым днем нужно вывести день недели, как это реализовать подскажите? Была идея такая,в цикле к каждому дню конкатенировать текущий месяц и год и преобразоывать во временную метку,и на основе нее вычислять день недели.Вот такой вариант,не знаю на сколько он правильный правда но рабочий.Если есть способ получше подкиньте идею.

```
<?php

        $day = '25';
        $month = date('m', time());
        $year = date('Y', time());

        $day_of_week = strtotime($month.'/'.$day.'/'.$year);
    ?>
```

Comment: А нельзя вычислить только для 1 числа месяца, а далее в цикле раскидать все семь дней недели?

Comment: Не совсем понял ваше идею

Comment: Эту идею уже успел написать в ответе Sergey Ronin . Смысл вычислять день недели для каждого дня месяца? Нужно вычислить только для одного. А остальные заполнить по порядку. Код, возможно, будет и длиннее, но по производительности Ваш вариант будет хуже, чем Sergey Ronin. Просто код пишется Вами один раз. А пользоваться им будут тысячи человек многократно. Поэтому производительность важнее в данном случае. Как другой вариант, можно еще создать сразу массив дней недели на 38 дней. И сдвигать его в зависимости от месяца.

Answer (score 1):

Не самый простой способ это вывести, но, как мне кажется, один из самых коротких по коду:

```
$week_days = ['пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб', 'вс'];

$first_day = new DateTime('2016-03-01');

$period = new DatePeriod($first_day, new DateInterval('P1D'), $first_day->format('t') - 1);

$snippets = [];

/** @var DateTime $day */
foreach ($period as $day) {
    $snippets[] = sprintf(
        '<span class="week-day">%s<br>%s</span>',
        $week_days[$day->format('w')],
        $day->format('j')
    );
}

echo sprintf('<div class="month-view">%s</div>', implode('', $snippets));
```

Основной смысл в том, что нужно содать период времени с первого по крайнее число месяца. Период — это такая вещь, которую можно обходить с помощью `foreach`, получая в качестве значения `DateTime` (который можно легко привести к нужному формату для вывода на экран).

Чтобы создать период с начала по конец месяца, понадобится указать `DateTime`, созданный от первого числа месяца, интервал (размер шага; так как нужно делать разбивку по дням, интервал будет создаваться от формулы `P1D` — шаг размером в один день) и количество повторений. Так как уже есть `$first_day`, из него можно вытащить количество дней в этом месяце (`$first_day->format('t')`) и вычесть единицу. Её нужно вычитать из-за того, что после первого шага в периоде будет две даты, после второго — три даты и так далее. Поэтому, чтобы получить 31 день в периоде, нужно делать 30 шагов.

При исполнении `foreach` можно взять для руссификации вручную сделанный массив с днями недели, а в качестве текущего индекса использовать `$day->format('w')`, который выводит номер дня недели начиная с нуля, где 0 — это понедельник, а 6 — воскресенье.

Остаётся только выбрать формат HTML-кода, в котором это будет выводиться.